# Why is the slope of an decreasing function is less than or equal to zero?

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)=(x^2+a)e^{-x}$ be a decreasing function on the set of real numbers. Find the range of a interval of the real numbers that allows a reduction in the total set of real numbers.

$${d\over dx} f(x)=2x \cdot e^{-x}-(x^2+a) \cdot e^{-x}
=(2x-x^2-a) \cdot e^{-x} \le 0$$
$$e^{-x} \gt 0,-x^2+2x-a \le 0\Rightarrow4-4a \le 0\Rightarrow4 \le 4a\Rightarrow1 \le a$$

Shouldn't it be $1 \lt a$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think about it carefully you will see that a function can be strictly decreasing even if its derivative has isolated zeros. Consider $f(x)=-x^3$ for a simple example.

Note also that "decreasing" can be used to mean "non-increasing" in some contexts, with "strictly decreasing" used for functions which are never stationary.